# Swift 3: lag between UIPickerView selection and UILabel refreshing

Tags: uipickerview, swift3

I have a UIPickerView which triggers implementing a lot of calculations once a particular row is selected. If a user waits for the calculations to finish, the UILabel (txtRunwayDest), showing the results of the calculations, successfully refreshes in about 5 seconds (while the calculations are taking place). To protect the application from users continuing to spin the UIPicker while calculations are being made (which may cause significant lag), I decided to show a pop-up view with a spinning activity indicator when a row is selected. I put the calculations on a background thread.

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtRunwayDest: UILabel!
let pckRunwayDest = UIPickerView()

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    if (pickerView == self.pckRunwayDest)
    {
        print("CHECK 0")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black()
        let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosBackground).async {

            ... // CODE


            if (row == 0)
            {
                ... // CODE
            }
            else
            {
                ... // CODE
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {

                print("CHECK DISPLAY")

                // Refresh all values on screen
                self.displayValues()

                // Dismiss the popup view
                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

            }
        } 
    }
}


func displayValues()
{
    if (someValue == nil)
    {
        self.txtRunwayDest.text = "Not selected";
    }
    else
    {
        print("START SHOWING TEXT")

        self.txtRunwayDest.text = appSingleton.runwayDestShared!.0 + " (" + appSingleton.runwayDestShared!.2 + ")"

        print("END SHOWING TEXT")
    }
}
```

So, everything works fine except that the txtRunwayDest text appears on the screen about 5-10 seconds after all calculations have been made and UIView has been dismissed. The console shows "END SHOWING TEXT" immediately after the main thread kicks in, but as I said, the label changes only after a significant lag.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Should be `DispatchQueue.main.sync()`

Comment: Not the same, you need to update the UI synchronously

Comment: I just changed the code to what you suggested and have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem by playing around with what code should be put in the background thread and which one in the main thread. In the long run, I put everything in DispatchQueue.main.sync, and everything works as expected. Thanks to Leo Dabus for valuable advice.